# Having multiple fields from my scrape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, screen-scraping

Iv'e done a screenscrape using nokogiri, it looks like this. In my teams model

```
      def pull_teams
        url = "http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html"
        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
        doc.css("tr.title:has(td:contains('Western')) ~tr").map do |team|
          team.search('td')[0].text
        end
      end
```

Iv'e already got

```
    require 'nokogiri'
    require 'open-uri'
```

In there also.

Iv'e got this in my teams controller

```
      def new
        @team = Team.new
        @team.refresh_teams
      end
```

In my view I have this

```
<% @teams.each do |team| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= link_to team.name, team %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', team, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_team_path(team) %></td>
            <% end %>
```

I want to be able to post team names and everything else on the table, if it helps my git is here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put a loop inside for `td`

```
doc.css("tr.title:has(td:contains('Western')) ~tr").map do |team|   
  team.search('td').map do |v|
    <td><%=v.text%><td>
  end
end
```